# Parsing Python to a list of instances

Tags: python, parsing

I want to parse Pure-Python Code into something like a list of instances of certain classes that represent various parts of the original code..

An example:

```
>>> text = '''
... for x in range(100):
...     print x
... '''
>>> tree = parse(text)
>>> print tree
Tree( ForLoop(x,Range(100), [Stmt(Print(x))]) )
# here ForLoop, Range, Stmt, Print are all custom classes
```

Comment: I don't have enough experience with it to give you a complete answer, but the built-in `ast` module documentation might get you started: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html

Comment: @Yuushi Yes even I was looking in the ast module.. But I am unable to figure out how to use it..

Comment: @nhahtdh The docs say: From Python 2.5 onward, it’s much more convenient to cut in at the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) generation and compilation stage, using the ast module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [*ast module*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ast.html#module-ast) has the tools you need:

```
>>> import ast
>>> text = '''
for x in range(100):
    print x
'''

>>> m = ast.parse(text)
>>> ast.dump(m)
"Module(body=[For(target=Name(id='x', ctx=Store()), iter=Call(func=Name(id='range', ctx=Load()),
       args=[Num(n=100)], keywords=[], starargs=None, kwargs=None), 
       body=[Print(dest=None, values=[Name(id='x', ctx=Load())], nl=True)], orelse=[])])"
```

Comment: I wonder how I can convert this into my version.. but well this will do for this question..

Comment: @Schoolboy: Your version is syntactically invalid as a python expression, due to the colon in the middle